# creating customized dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu which is same as the image below.

.[image]

```
 <div class="dropdown dropdown-select signup-dd">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle signup-btn"  type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- expanded="true">
    Select Title
     <span class="caret downarrow-signup"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu ul-signup" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <%# @themes.each do |t| %>
       <li role="presentation" class="dd-li">
       <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#dropdownMenu122').text('Mr.');$('#user_title').val('<%="Mr."%>');" ><%="Mr."%></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="dd-li" >
       <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#dropdownMenu122').text('Ms.');$('#user_title').val('<%="Ms."%>');"><%="Ms."%></a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="dd-li">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#dropdownMenu122').text('Mrs.');$('#user_title').val('<%="Mrs."%>');"><%="Mrs."%></a></li>
    <%# end %>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

There's a border image and a seperator image which needs to be applied to the `<ul>` and `<li>` of the `<select>` for `<dropdown>`.

I am not able to trace down the issue. Probably completely confused with the  number of classes and the property. Can someone help me hunt down the issue.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh1cuonh/1/).

Comment: May I ask what's the point of this? Why wouldn't one take the HTML elements `select` and `option` for creating this?

Comment: this was been written this way and I need to get the dropdown fixed and hence I didn't want to put lot of time and eventually have lost a lot of time just changing the css here and there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following,

in your `.ul-signup> li > a` add `border-bottom: 1px solid #000;`

and also add

```
#dropdownMenu1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Here is the [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codotronix/qh1cuonh/3/)

And to add the border you just need to add border to the `ul` element.

********* **UPDATED WITH IMAGE SEPARATOR** *********************

I used a random line image from google because your image appeared too whitey to me.

Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codotronix/qh1cuonh/16/)

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, just let me check it once again @Suraj

Comment: Hi, check the updated fiddle now. Used image as separator this time. Your image appeared too whitey to me so I used a random image from google. But you should be able to change the image to use your own one. @Suraj

Comment: Just a quick update. The image reference I used from google has changed. So, image position that I used -276px needs to be corrected to -75px for the example to work.. :)

Comment: an u[pdated fiddle in support of my prev comment http://jsfiddle.net/qh1cuonh/18/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with border-bottom and border-color

Change your ul-signup>li>a to

.ul-signup> li > a {

```
 display: block;
  background-position: 10px bottom;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/OdpE6ba.png");
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color:#C8C8C8;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qh1cuonh/2/

Comment: hey Rachel, Thanks but instead of that border I want to use that image as a seperator and not that line

Comment: @Suraj when i enter that url in my browser nothing shows up

Comment: Yes, because it is white in color. Inspect element and change the body color to black in the browser, you'll be able to see the seperator of color white

Comment: @Suraj then i don't understand the problem

Comment: No problem Rachel, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

First off, why not use Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/

Second,
If you want to add in image inside a li or ul you can do this in a couple of ways, one of which is

```
<li>
     <img src="path/to/image"></img>
<li>
```

Another way to accomplish this is in css add a background to the `<li>` and giving it an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
  background-position: 10px bottom;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/OdpE6ba.png");
```

from this css selector `.ul-signup> li > a` , i have replaced ur border image in css selector `.dd-li`  because it not that much visible

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh1cuonh/6/)

Comment: the selection is not occuring in your fiddle

Comment: selection is not happening in your fiddle itself right?. can you clarify `me border image is not showing or selection` not happening for which you have posted this question?